# node.js (express.js) (mongodb database) and react contact form combining problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, mongodb, nosql

I want react contact form and mongodb combining but i have a problem. I want to write a program that will save the data from the contact form to MongoDB using React. Please help me...

[image: javacript error]

my (serviscagir.jsx) react code:

```
const serviscagir = () => {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        name: '',
        email: '',
        number: '',
        message: ''
    });

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            const response = await fetch('/api/submit-form', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: Object.fromEntries(formData),
            });

            const result = await response.json();
            console.log(result.message);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        }
    };
```

my (server.js) node.js code:

```
const express = require("express")
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")


const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5174;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const formDataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String,
  number: String,
  message: String
});

const FormData = mongoose.model('FormData', formDataSchema);

app.post('/api/submit-form', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { name, email, number, message } = req.body;

    const formData = new FormData({
      name,
      email,
      number,
      message
    });

    await formData.save();
    res.status(201).json({ message: 'Form data submitted successfully!' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
});
```

I tried to do it with help from chatgpt but I couldn't do it.

Comment: Please let us know what is happening: data showing up in MongoDB? Errors/exceptions in the Express logs?  Errors/exceptions in the browser? Is the browser's NETWORK showing that the POST was successful?  Posting code with no description of what is actually happening is not very useful.